# Inconsistent behavior of injecting content script in chrome store and local build

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

We've observed that when `chrome.extension.isAllowedFileSchemeAccess` is disabled, injecting a content script for any local files under `file:///` protocol only works on local build but not when its uploaded in chrome store?

Additionally, the behavior when toggling the file access under `chrome://extensions` is also inconsistent.

In local build, it is invoked as `update` but not when uploaded in chrome store.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    if(details.reason == "install"){
        //call a function to handle a first install
    }else if(details.reason == "update"){
        //call a function to handle an update
    }
});
```

[image]

Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: 1) In an unpacked extension file access is enabled by default and isAllowedFileSchemeAccess is true, so file:// injection works because of that. If you disable file access manually in an unpacked extension, then injection won't work either. 2) I'd call this inconsistency a bug, which you can report in https://crbug.com.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. For some reason, it seems that dynamic script injection still works for unpacked extension when file access is disabled.

I can't seem to see it on the documentation. Is the expected behavior that once file access is disabled any type of content script (either throught manifest.json declaration or script injection) will not work on local files?

Comment: Injection doesn't work in this scenario for me. If it does for you it's a bug.

Comment: After creating a minimal barebones extension, i was able to verify that it was indeed a bug on our extension.